# Passing an array to pthread_create

Tags: c, pthreads

So i was trying to make a program that creates a thread in c whose job is to find the maximum of 2 given numbers. The first program that i wrote (named askisi.c) was the following:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int max;

void *max_of_two(void *param);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid;

    pthread_attr_t attr;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
            fprintf(stderr,"You have to give 2 numbers... \n");
            return -1;
    }

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    pthread_create(&tid,&attr,max_of_two,argv);
    pthread_join(tid,NULL);
    printf("max = %d\n",max);
}

void *max_of_two(void *param)
{
    if(atoi(*param[1]) >= atoi(*param[2]))
            max = atoi(*param[1]);
    else
            max = atoi(*param[2]);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

But using gcc in Linux i got these errors:
[image]

Now after a lot of research i found that my the function `max_of_two` should be written like this:

```
void *max_of_two(void *param)
{
    char **arguments = (char**)param; 

    if(atoi(arguments[1]) >= atoi(arguments[2])){
            max = atoi(arguments[1]);}
    else
            max = atoi(arguments[2]);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

The first problem is that i didn't find any explanation on why my first program didn't work. The second one is that i didn't find an understandable explanation on what the instruction `char **arguments = (char**)param;` actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void` is not a real type, and in that context it means the function expect any type and its up to the programmer to decide which is done with `casting`.

So by doing `char **arguments = (char**)param;` you casted param into `char **` and assigned that cast to the variable `arguments`.

Comment: Ok but why after this casting im refering to an element with `arguments[1]` and not `*arguments[1]`?

Comment: `arguments` is a pointer to an array of char (to make it easier to understand we can say its a pointer to an array of strings). So, if you want to access the first array of char(or string) you can either use `*(arguments + pos)` or `arguments[pos]` as they are equivalent. Also `arguments` it self points to `arguments[0]`.

I suggest to read about `array subscripts in C` [http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/embed/chap8/chap8.htm] to get a better idea